# Parse string on html source code

Tags: java, selenium, parsing

this is my very first question here. I have already followed this website for a long time and found a lot of information thanks to you guys. So, I want to first thank you sincerely for all these amazing works and answers you post.

I am currently working for a import/export online shop and look for some optimization for our prestashopweb daily task. I use Java and the API Selenium and work on Chrome Driver.

I am looking for a way to remove a product quantity depending its specification(colors, ohm, mg...). For example. if a customer has ordered 1 product yellow color, I have to first parse the yellow string on his order page where there is the product. Then I have to go on the product page and remove 1 piece on the yellow color quantity text field.

Everything is ok, beside one thing. Parse a String on the HTML code source and try to match it with another String on an other page. Maybe with xpath?

Here are the pictures for a better understanding.
Hello, it is just a script which opens my back office account, and make actions for me. For example

int productNumber = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='orderProducts']/tbody/tr")).size()-3;

```
            for(int i = 1 ; i<=productNumber ; i++) 
            {
                int quantité = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='orderProducts']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[4]")).getText());

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='orderProducts']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]/a/span[@class='productName']")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']/a[@id='link-Quantities']")).click();

            }
```

Pack Box AIO 70W - Teslacigs
Couleur : Yellow
                                    Réf. PA70WT

Comment: For me it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to test something or are you taking about action handling?

Comment: Hello, it is about action handling. It is not for test. Maybe it is not very well explained. I want to remove manually from a shopping cart of a customer for all his products. Some of these products have declination ( color, number of nicotine, Ohm value...), so I have to first store the declination in a string variable, and then match it with the one on the product quantity page, if it matches, the code remove the product quantity. But I just don't know how to parse something inside the value of a webelement or between two string.

Comment: So if it is about action handling how is it related to selenium? If you want to process the data from the shopping cart you would do it in the backend action handling where you have - for example - java objects ...

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Hello, it is just a script which opens my back office account, and make actions for me. For example

Comment: Can you elaborate what is your task here in simpler terms? Like you are iterating an element set and extracting the quantity and after that what is the action you need to perform and what is the problem you are facing?